# How to get rid of space between input and calendar icon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Update:

[image]

after implementing this code here is what I'm getting:

```
<div class="col-xs-5">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="" class="col-xs-5 control-label">Contract Date Signed:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-5">
         @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ContractDateSigned, new { htmlAttributes = new { @Value = Convert.ToDateTime(Model.ContractDateSigned).ToShortDateString(), @class = "form-control" } }) 
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ContractDateSigned, "", new { @class = "text-danger"
         })
         <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

How to get-rid of the space between input and a calendar icon?

[image]

here is my html that uses:

```
<div class="col-xs-5">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="" class="col-xs-5 control-label">Contract Date Signed:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-5">
         @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ContractDateSigned, new { htmlAttributes = new { @Value = Convert.ToDateTime(Model.ContractDateSigned).ToShortDateString(), @class = "form-control" } })                                                
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ContractDateSigned, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
      </div>
      <span class="btn btn-default"><span class=" fa fa-calendar"></span></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For btn `position:absolute; left:0;` If not work give the left value in minus `left:-5px`

Answer (score 2):

Use an input group:

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups

```
<div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="" class="col-xs-5 control-label">
      Contract Date Signed:
    </label>
    <div class="input-group col-xs-5">
      <input class="form-control">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/21Lfnq4e/

[image]

Comment: I can not use any other theme except that bootstrap which is what i am using in my code

Comment: That is Bootstrap, what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-xs-5">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">Contract Date Signed:</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
         <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
      </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no.  wrap div around span. like this example [plunker] (http://plnkr.co/edit/oZ8Gy2rmG9qxU2UeizVM)

Comment: @AbuHamzah could you vote/accept the answer if you find it useful?

Comment: I'm using bs 3.2 ver and I have fork the plnkr and its not showing the image, pls have a look at it  http://plnkr.co/edit/ppj6X0Vjjkt6lUY9sbzi?p=preview

Comment: you're calling fa fa-calendar in the span class, which is fontawesomes font library, not bootstraps.  bootstrap uses it's own font library which is also not being called in your plunker example.